# Path parameters in Lamda functions w/ API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to create a create a GET request in the API Gateway console but I keep geeting an error, and I don't understand why.

The request I am trying to create is the following:

```
GET /user/{user-id}
```

I am able to create the resource for this request, however, the moment I try adding the GET method in it, I keep getting the following error:

```
 Expected params.requestParameters['method.request.path.user-id'] to be a boolean
```

I don't really understand why this is happening, and my google searches have not been helpful.

Here is a screenshot of the resource creation for /user/{user-id} in api gateway:

[image]

Edit: I tried testing it with just a normal GET request using a normal endpoint (without a path parameter) and it seems to be working just fine. This leads me to believe that I am definitely doing something wrong with the path parameters.

Comment: Maybe an AWS bug?  (just noticed another similar question just posted around the same time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70454601/strange-issue-with-the-api-gateway)

Comment: I think it is a bug, since I ended up using OpenApi to make the endpoint instead of the console